# Highlight.js not working with marked - returning TypeError: (e || "").toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: highlight.js

I'm using (client/browser side, not in Node):

- Marked 9: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked@9.0.3/lib/marked.umd.min.js"></script>`
- Highlight.js 11: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.3.1/highlight.min.js"></script>`
- Marked-highlight: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked-highlight/lib/index.umd.js"></script>`

and I'm having trouble with simple example from the docs - when the language is know the code breaks.

I have this code:

```
  const markedRenderer = new marked.Marked(
    markedHighlight.markedHighlight({
      langPrefix: 'hljs language-',
      highlight(code, lang) {
        if ( ['nohighlight', 'plaintext'].includes(('' + lang).trim())) {
          return code;
        } else {
          const language = hljs.getLanguage(lang);
          if (typeof language === 'undefined') {
            return hljs.highlightAuto(code).value;
          } else {
            console.log("highlighting", lang, language)
            return hljs.highlight(code, { language, ignoreIllegals: true }).value;
          }
        }
      }
    })
  );
```

First two branches work fine (plaintext and auto), but the last branch - when the language is known - breaks with the following message:

```
highlight.min.js:273 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (e || "").toLowerCase is not a function
Please report this to https://github.com/markedjs/marked.
    at v (highlight.min.js:273:33)
    at f (highlight.min.js:233:31)
    at Object.h [as highlight] (highlight.min.js:184:28)
    at Object.highlight (47153:1421:25)
    at R.walkTokens (index.umd.js:35:30)
    at n.walkTokens (Instance.ts:201:48)
    at R.walkTokens (Instance.ts:31:45)
    at R.parse (Instance.ts:253:26)
    at 47153:1567:33
```

The `hljs.getLanguage(lang);` works fine and console.log prints out:

```
highlighting C 
{
{name: 'C', aliases: Array(1), keywords: {…}, disableAutodetect: true, illegal: '</', …} aliases : ['h'] contains : (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] disableAutodetect : true exports : {preprocessor: {…}, strings: {…}, keywords: {…}} illegal 
....
```

The code snippet in md is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  puts("hello"); 
  return 0;
}
```

So, esentially, when I delete the "C" the auto-highlight kicks-in and it works fine, but when the language is assigned it breaks.

What am I missing?

### EDIT:

here is a pen: https://codepen.io/Igor-Mekterovi/pen/LYMOaGJ

Just delete the "C" in the line with four backticks, wait few seconds, and see that the highlightAuto works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is this: on the line

```js
return hljs.highlight(code, { language, ignoreIllegals: true }).value;
```

`language` is expected to be the language name (a string).

However, `hljs.getLanguage(lang)` returns an object. This value that is an object but was expected to be a string is the minified `e` in the error message you get. The actual non-minified function is [`getLanguage`](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/11.3.0/src/highlight.js#L873), called from [highlight](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/11.3.0/src/highlight.js#L136).

The solution is to replace the above mentioned line with something like:

```js
return hljs.highlight(code, {language: language.name, ignoreIllegals: true }).value;
```